# how to read and write a value to a json file $true or $false. If the script opened the first time

Tags: json, powershell

PowerShell Script

```
$TestPath = '.\test.json'
[bool]$TP = Test-Path -Path $TestPath -PathType Leaf
IF ($TP)
{
    $Content = Get-Content '.\test.json' | ConvertFrom-Json 
    $FirstOpen = @($Data.Config.First)
    if ($FirstOpen -eq '$true')
    {
        Write-Warning "Show disclaimer !"
        $FirstOpen.$Data.Config.First = '$False'                               # error line
        $Content | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content '.\test.json' -Encoding utf-8  # error line
    }
    ELSE
    {
        Write-Host "This file has already been opened for the first time !"
    }
}
ELSE
{
    Write-Host "The config file not exist."
    Start-Sleep -s 5
    exit
}
pause
```

when I want to change the true value to false the whole file gets erased.
here the json file : Test.json

```
{"Config": {
 "first" : "$True"

}}
```

thank you

I don't know if I have $Content or $FirstOpen to change $True to $False.

I try to change some value, but not working.

```
$FirstOpen.$Data.Config.First = '$False'                               # error line
$Content | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content '.\test.json' -Encoding utf-8  # error line
```

Comment: What is `$Data` ? Also booleans shouldn't be quoted, `'$False'` should be just `$False`

Comment: The '$False' is only a flag. I don't need write dollar sign like this $. Is just a textual form not a bool. thank

Comment: then you condition `if ($FirstOpen)` is wrong because a string containing any word (`$False`) still evaluates to `$True`. It should be literally `if ($FirstOpen -eq '$True')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because you're referencing a variable that doesn't exist (`$Data`), it should be `$Content` instead.

```
$FirstOpen = @($Data.Config.First)
```

If you want to make it work, your code should be:

```
$TestPath = '.\test.json'
if (Test-Path -Path $TestPath -PathType Leaf) {
    $Content = Get-Content '.\test.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
    if ($Content.Config.First) {
        Write-Warning 'Show disclaimer !'
        $Content.Config.First = $false # no quotes otherwise it is interpreted as string
        $Content | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content '.\test.json' -Encoding utf-8
    }
    else {
        Write-Host 'This file has already been opened for the first time !'
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host 'The config file not exist.'
    Start-Sleep -s 5
    return
}
```

Your Json should look like:

```json
{
  "Config": {
    "first": true // or false, no quotes otherwise it is interpreted as string
  }
}
```

Comment: a minor suggestion: use `$TestPath` with `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` as well.